# BJT: what are differences between \$r_{be}\$ and \$r_e\$; \$r_{in}\$ and \$r_{in(t)}\$?

Tags: transistors, bjt

On the topic of small signal analysis in my textbook *Transistor Circuit Techniques: Discrete and Integrated; 3rd Edition, G.J Ritchie*, I encounter the two pairs of terms: \$r_{be}\$ and \$r_e\$; \$r_{in}\$ and \$r_{in}(t)\$, but cannot find a definition that clearly distinguishes them. Can someone clarify the difference between the members of these two pairs and perhaps their prose names? In particular, I see \$r_{in}(t)\$ used in some AC equivalent models but not others. In what ways is it different from \$r_{in}\$?

Also in this textbook, it says to determine \$r_{out}\$ by short-circuiting the input voltage source (\$v_{in}\$ I assume) and applying a voltage across the output terminals. I don't understand what the former means.

Comment: What textbook? They don't all use the same notations.

Comment: Transistor Circuit Techniques Discrete and Integrated 3rd Edition, G.J Ritchie.

Answer (score 2):

\$r_{be}\$ stands for the resistance located in the path of Base to Emitter (and reverse, it's bidirectional) which is actually placed in Base side and needs to be multiplied to \$\beta\$ if you want to move it to Emitter. It's also known as \$r_{\pi}\$.

\$r_{e}\$ stands for the total resistance seen from Emitter of a transistor, in approximate:

\$r_{e} = \beta r_{\pi} || r_{o} \approx \beta r_{\pi}\$

\$r_{o}\$ is the resistance between Emitter and Collector of a BJT which is infinite as usual in approximations.

---

In high frequencies, some capactive behaviors will be appeared in BJT Transistors. \$r_{in}\$ stands for the input resistance seen usually from Base and it gets time variant if capacitors appear in transistor model, so you'll have a time-dependent resistance in high frequencies notationed as \$r_{in}(t)\$. It's related to advanced topics of BJT transistors.

Comment: Hi, my textbook say opposite, it is \$r_{be}=(1+\beta) r_e \$ and in small signal analysis, only \$r_{be}\$ is used.

Answer (score 0):

rbe = resistance between the base and emitter terminals
re = the resistance at the emitter terminal
I believe rin is the input impedance at the base